# Why do I get a PropertyReferenceException with methodname?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I get following Exception when I try to build my maven project:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'performanceDao': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: 
No property customSearch found for type Performance!
```

I am using Spring with hibernate and java 1.8.
I just wanna create my own query method.

The exception itself doesn't make sense to me, because i do not have a property customSearch, customSearch is my method.I allready tried other methodnames and evrething i can find over google.

I suppose it has something todo with the nameing conventions of the classes.

The relevant minimal code parts are:

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PerformanceDao extends JpaRepository<Performance,Integer>,PerformanceRepositoryCustom {
}
```

Custom interface:

```
public interface PerformanceRepositoryCustom {
    public List<Performance> customSearch(Performance x, Integer durationDiff);
}
```

Interface implementation:

```
@Repository
public class PerformanceRepositoryImpl implements PerformanceRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public PerformanceRepositoryImpl() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Performance> customSearch(Performance x, Integer durationDiff){
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: The problem is the naming of your types.

You have to rename the interface PerformanceDao to PerformanceRepository, so you have the following types:

- PerformanceRepository
- PerformanceRepositoryCustom
- PerformanceRepositoryImpl

Comment: You also have to make sure that all the files are in the same package. Thanks!